# My App Error on Jelly Bean Simulator

Tags: android, string, text, int

i'm sorry if there is a question like this
i just wanna know, i'm trying to read file .txt on server and i convert to int and
i have succeed when i try on froyo simulator

this is my code

```
final Context context = this;
TextView textServer, textApp;
final String textSource = "http://xxx/dev/android/androidversi.txt";
```

DECLARATION FOR LOCATION OF .txt file

```
URL textUrl;
String StringBuffer;
String stringText = "";

try {
    textUrl = new URL(textSource);
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

    while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        stringText += StringBuffer;
    }
    bufferReader.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

CODE ABOVE READS .txt FILE FROM SERVER AND THIS CODE WHICE ARE ERRORS IN JELLY BEAN, BECAUSE I'VE TRIED ON FROYO IS RUNNING NORMALLY

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = manager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    int version = info.versionCode;

    if(Integer.parseInt(stringText)>version) // I'VE CONVERTED STRING FROM .txt TO INT SO THAT I CAN COMPARE IT WITH VERSION ON APP
    {
        // IF VERSION ON SERVER > VERSION APP THERE IS LINK TO DOWNLOAD HERE
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

compare the version

Please help me :'(

Comment: Post the crash report from logcat

Comment: problem fixed with code from @MoJo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its nothing but the Network on main thread exception; Just include

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

to your code (in onCreate() method) and you'll be fine :)

Comment: Strict mode is a method of avoiding network actions in main thread; introduced from 3.0 Honeycomb; the code just tells if the target version is above froyo, it'll turn off strict mode:)

Comment: i change 9 (num that you write on code) to 8, is it problem?
btw is it code safety and no effects?

Comment: thanks, dude :). btw do you understand about blackberry programming?

Comment: unfortunately i've played with only Android and ios for now; will learn it soon:) sorry for now

Comment: The correct solution is to **get the networking code off the main application thread**. This "solution" is merely burying one's head in the sand.